# How can i add another data in the next column using VB6

Tags: excel, csv, vb6

I have a script in VB6 that will parse a CSV file and get only the needed data. I used **`Writeline`** to write the data in the **CSV file**. My problem is how can I write the next data into the next column in CSV file using `VB6`?

**like this sample output.**

[image]

and **NOT LIKE THIS**

[image]

**Below is my code in parsing data and writing in CSV/Excel file**

```
Dim myFSOww As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFSOr As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFSOw
Dim ft1 As TextStream
//This myFSOw is where my CSV file located which I will use for the write
Set myFSOw = myFSOww.GetFile("C:\Users\user\Documents\bebe folder\Desktop\LTE Raw Data\b.csv")
Set myFSOr = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = myFSOr.GetFile(txtfilename.Text)
Set ft1 = ts.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
Set ft2 = myFSOw.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting)
//
//This is the start of reading data. It will parse the CSV file
Do Until ft1.AtEndOfStream
    On Error Resume Next
      a = ft1.ReadLine
      b = a
      r = r + 1
      a = Split(a, ",")
      z = left(b, 1)
If Not IsNumeric(z) Then
   For i = 0 To Ubound(a)
      Text1 = a(i)
         If Text1 <> "" And txt1 = ""  Then
            txt1 = Text1
            Text1 = ""
         ElseIf txt1 <> "" And txt2 = "" Then
            txt2 = Text1
            Text1 = ""
         ElseIf txt3 = "" Then
            txt3 = Text1
            Text1 = ""
         ElseIf txt4 = "" Then
            txt4 = Text1
            Text1 = ""
         End If
   Next
//
//In this code, it will write the parse data in another CSV file which the output must be like the first picture below

If txt1 <> "" And txt2 <> "" And txt3 <> "" And txt4 <> "" Then
    ft2.WriteLine txt1
    ft2.WriteLine txt2
    ft2.WriteLine txt3
    ft2.WriteLine txt4
End If

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
writeline ExistingLine & "," & NewField
```

Is your data text quoted.

```
writeline ExistingLine & "," & """NewField"""
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have tried this and it's working but it is not in line of the first data.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, perhaps. Are you wanting to make many lines into one line? If so don't use writeline. Concatinate the strings you want how you want, and my answer shows the principal, and then write at the end of your program. Writeline adds a line ending. If concatinating ifyou want a line ending you have to add it yourself.

Comment: see the sample above. What i need is a script that will write a data per column. for example i have a data like this: first line: "Food, Apple, Orange, Mango" second line: "Drinks, Water, Juice, Tea". When i write it in excel it should be per column like the excel photo above.

Comment: There is no photo. Why do you talk about excel. This is about csv files. I think my comments address your general issue.

Comment: i have edited my question, added photo to my question kindly review it. thank you

Comment: The photo doesn't exist. http://i.stack.imgur.com/CaYdA.jpg can't be found. Do you want everything on one line or one per line?

Comment: what i need is like this output in CSV or in Excel file

`Food  | Drinks `
`Apple | Water `
`Orange| Juice `
`Mango | Tea`

Comment: I have that server blocked in my hosts file. I've temp unblocked it, but now I've seen it I'm still confused. The answer is simple but ... What does your source data look like for the output you show? How are you parsing the line? My previous comment is the general principal you need to use. I can be specific if I see the details.

Comment: i will put another photo again for my current output.

Comment: You don't need to, I unblocked it.

Comment: the second photo is my output using your code 
`writeline ExistingLine & "," & NewField`

Comment: what i need output is the first photo

Comment: That was because I thought you wanted everything on one line. What does your source data look like and how are you parsing it. You need to post code. It's hard to imagine what you are doing to get your second photo, you are certainly doing it wrong. Post your full code. And sample 4 line of data. And post them as text not pictures.

Comment: Your code is difficult to understand. Describe the rules and the sample data.

Comment: You need to explin your rules and sample data.